# Manage lists of apps

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Is there such a functionality or app that enables you to manage lists of apps in Play Store?

I want to have lists of apps stored somewhere on the cloud and install an entire list at once. Such a functionality will be useful when you buy a new phone and install all your favorite apps without having to remember them or browse Play Store.

Comment: I really don't understand why my question got downvoted ... If you're doing something like this, a comment will be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect your Google-Account with the PlayStore and allows it to save all your installs. Now if your sign into your account on the new phone you get a lost of all apps you installed ehile you are logged in into this account. Sure you still had to install every app again, but you dont have to search again ;)

Comment: That's not gonna do it. This it the list of all apps you installed over time on all your devices, including tablets. There are apps that you don't want to install on your phone or maybe you just tested once. I know you can remove apps from that list, but it's too much of a hassle. I wanted something more convenient.